# 401 bad credentials with good credentials

Tags: active-directory, artifactory, saml-2.0

I have an Artifactory server (5.6.2) set up with SAML SSO and I'm trying to use my personal admin credentials to download a file:

https://internalartifactory/artifactory/prerelease/package/package.1.2.3.nupkg

However, I continually receive "401 Bad Credentials". I can enter the credentials of a non-administrator, non-SAML account with an internal password and the download will complete. I can also sign into the GUI with my admin credentials and download it. However, other users need the ability to authenticate through a script with their AD credentials.

My problem sounds like the exact one from this jfrog forum [post](http://forums.jfrog.org/RESTAPI-over-https-and-ldap-td7579421.html) but, when I follow the [solution](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Centrally+Secure+Passwords) given there, I have no way to generate an encrypted password. I suspect this is because we are using SAML but I don't want to have to generate an encrypted password or to have to use API keys. Both of those seem like an unnecessary headache to explain to a lot of new users.

How can I programmatically authenticate through SAML to download this file directly from a script? This is what I'm using and it works ok for the non-SAML credentials with an internal password but not for SAML credentials:

```
$credentials = Get-Credential
Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile $tempPath -Credential $credentials -Uri $url
```

Thanks!